Flutter TextFormField force native OS emoji keyboard (iOS and Android)
I would like for a text input box to display the native emoji selector when the user is trying to input something.
TextField have the TextInputType keyboardType property, but it seems like there is no native option for the emoji keyboard.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputType-class.html
I know it can be done for numericals (numpad) or dates (calendar sliders) but can we force flutter to display the emoji selector automatically? Otherwise the user has to press the emoji button on the virtual keyboard that spawns.
I have tried available packages like these :
https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_selector
https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter
But neither would work as good as just displaying the native emoji keyboard directly.
